# chrome extension background page sock.js Socket connection lost on OSX sleep

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sockjs

My current client is a radio station.
They use sockets to push data.
Some examples

- song play  (contains song info, thumb, playlists, artist info and
  more)
- program start (program info, dj's and more)

The extention I built has a socket listening script built in.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/q-music-nl/mhobnnhfmhcnomoehjomodcjmcjhfaea

The socket listening is done via  "SockJS client, version 0.3.4, http://sockjs.org, MIT License".

This is built in the back.html  like so:

MANIFEST

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "NAME",
  "description": "DESC",
  "version": "3.1",
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Click to start",
    "default_icon" : "Q.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": { 
    "page": "back.html"
    },
  "options_page": "options.html"

}
```

BACK.HTML

```
<script src="back.js">

</script>
```

BACK.JS

```
function init() {

(function(){

    var a = document.createElement('script');

    a.type = 'text/javascript';

    a.async = true;

    a.src = 'sock.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);

})();

} 
window.onload = init;
```

This works perfect!

The problem is after resuming my MAC (Software  OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)) from sleep the connection seems to be lost.
No loggings in back html console, no other indications, just no communication over the wire anymore.
The pushes are there however.
What am I doing wrong?

*edit you may email me for the full source code of the extension.

Comment: Let me see some manifest !

Comment: added in full manifest.

Comment: May I ask, why aren't you just including `sock.js` in `back.html` directly ? BTW, you have been using some obsolete syntax in your manifest (e.g. `name`, `page` etc). Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to your question. If you are willing to send me the full source code, I promise to take a deeper look into it (my e-mail is on my profile - if you read really carefully and do the math :D).

Comment: why not in the html, because I had it somewhere in js already.
It triggers an event written in the same file. I dont know? Just because?
#mailsent

Comment: I played around with the full code, but other than verifyign that there is the same problem on Windows 8, I couldn't find anything useful (say...a solution). It seems to be an issue of the `audio` element not resuming playback correctly. A reload of the background page (after appropriately persisting (and later restoring) the `paused` variable) seems to solve the problem, but I can't suggest any efficient way to decide when to do a reload (e.g. you could reload upon receiving a message through SockJS, but it won't solve the problem until after a new message has arrived).